# Getting values from Checkbox into Slack

Tags: php, forms, slack

I'm building a contact form for a client (creative agency) that whenever someone fills it in, it'll get sent to a specific channel in Slack.

Everything works fine apart from the list of jobs. What happens is that when someone ticks off more than 1, Slack will only show the first job. I want all jobs to show!

**form.php**

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Graphics" name="job[]">Graphic Design
<input type="checkbox" value="Branding" name="job[]">Branding
<input type="checkbox" value="Illustration" name="job[]">Illustration
<input type="submit" name="submit">
```

**output.php**

```
function job_list() {
$job = $_POST['job'];

    for($x=0; $x < count($job); $x++) {
        return $job[$x] . ",";
    }

}

//Putting it all together.
$text = "Jobs:" . job_list();
```

**What I get in Slack**

```
Jobs:Graphics,
```

Comment: Please read `return` [documentation](http://php.net/return). That will stop execution of that function on the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: @jonStirling I've tried echo but it doesn't work, return is the closest to what I want.

Comment: `return implode(', ', $job)` instead of the loop?

Comment: That works! :) @JonStirling

Comment: Please, @JonStirling or OP post as an answer to the question and not just a comment. And OP, you'll need to accept the answer...

Comment: @WattsInABox I actually included the working solution in my edit thanks to Jon, which for some reason got re-edited by Halfer to exclude it.

Comment: looks like the answer is back. If you don't mind accepting it, that will clear up our queues a tiny bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

```
return implode(', ', $job) instead of the loop
```